# Return back json data to $.ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have got back response at this line in form of json from web api controller action:

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The short version of the response is something like this:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "ResponseStatus": 1,
        "Error": {
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "ErrorMessage": ""
        },
        "TraceId": "83b04f8c-f7dd-4755-9767-b0c861ea9e28",
        "Origin": "DEL",
        "Destination": "BOM",
        "Results": [
            [{
                "ResultIndex": "OB12",
                "Source": 6,
                "Fare": {
                    "Currency": "INR",
                    "OtherCharges": 58.29,
                    "ChargeBU": [{
                        "key": "TBOMARKUP",
                        "value": 8.29
                    }, {
                        "key": "CONVENIENCECHARGE",
                        "value": 0
                    }, {
                        "key": "OTHERCHARGE",
                        "value": 50.00
                    }],
                    "Discount": 0,
                },
            }]
        ]
    }
}
```

The full version is shown at http://pastebin.com/eEE72ySk

Then i am returning back HttpResponse from webApi Controller by sending this json var data to CreateResponse method and returning back res like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
return res;
```

I have to return back this res to $.ajax function on view page:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
    type: "Post",
    data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()}, true),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            items.push(key + ' : ' + val + '</br>');
        });    
    }
});
```

I can see the whole content in alert box.
I want to know how to loop through each and every data i got back and assign their values to the respective `<div>` elements on the view page. The Response which i got back contains several arrays and arrays into arrays. I am confused how to manage each and every data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are accessed with indexers and for an array containing an array, you use

```
XXX[0][0].YYY
```

to access the first array within the first array.

The code to access some of your properties would be

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
    type: "Post",
    data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()}, true),
    success: function (data) {
        var responseStatus = data.Response.ResponseStatus; // returns 1
        var errorCode = data.Response.Error.ErrorCode; // returns 0
        var origin = data.Response.Origin; // returns 'DEL'
        var resultIndex = data.Response.Results[0][0].ResultIndex; // returns 'OB12'
    }
});
```

Most of the data in the arrays seems to contain only one object, or one array containing one object and if that is always the case, then accessing it using `[0]` or `[0][0]` will be fine.

For the arrays containing multiple objects such as `data.Response.Results[0][0].Fare.ChargeBU`, you can use a `for` loop or `$.each()` loop, for example

```
$.each(data.Response.Results[0][0].Fare.ChargeBU, function (index, chargeBU) {
    var key = chargeBU.key // returns "TBOMARKUP", "CONVENIENCECHARGE", "OTHERCHARGE"
});
```

Comment: I have tried this:  $.each(data.Response.Results, function (i, item) {
                                            $("#results1").append('<p>' + item.Name + '</p>');
                                        }); Error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Results' of undefined. same error was for var responseStatus right now i have commented out all the four var.

Comment: Its not `$.each(data.Response.Results, function (i, item) { ` its `$.each(data.Response.Results[0][0].Fare.ChargeBU, function (index, chargeBU) {` - you need to read the answer carefully. And I have tested all this and its works fine. If your still having troubles, I'll create a fiddle to prove it.

Comment: Then the data you have shown in that image is not what your really getting. I'll create a fiddle for you a bit later (give me 30-40 min)

Comment: Sir,In Results its giving me back 25 arrays, i am showing u two in this link:http://pastebin.com/YNthgivV as u said i tried THIS:`var responseStatus = data.Response.ResponseStatus;  $('#divResult1').append(responseStatus);` but its giving me error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ResponseStatus' of undefined

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/) - click on the button and it will display `"1"` (i.e. the value of `data.Response.ResponseStatus`)

Comment: Have just updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/1/) to add all 4 items I showed in the answer (click on all the buttons). If you are getting and error, its because the data your getting is not the data you showed in your question, but  but really makes no difference - you just use the same format - if its a `{` then use a `.` (dot) and if its a `[` then its an array so use `[#]`

Comment: And another updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/2/) to show the each loop.

Comment: VERY very big thanks there is something small missing, i will pick it out soon. as far as ques is concerned, i am fully satisfied with the way u provided to pick each and every data @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Can u tell me how to iterate each array in results if results consist of multiple array like this :http://pastebin.com/F6nPGmcs i have tried this: `$.each(data.Response.Results[0][0], function (i, item) {
                                $("#divResult1").append('<p>' + item.AirlineRemark + '</p>');
                            });` it should return different airline name.. any suggestion

Comment: @duke, No time just now but I will update the fiddle with the new data in a few hours

Comment: It needs to be `$.each(data.Response.Results[0], function(i, item) {`

Comment: THEN THE OUTPUT IS 0 ([object Object]) 1 ([object Object])2 ([object Object]) AND so on

Comment: Yes, but then you need to access the properties. I'll update the fiddle in about 30 min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112683/discussion-between-duke-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
{
    url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
    type: "Post",
    data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()}, true),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var items = [];
        $.each(data.Response.Results, function (key, val) {
            items.push(key + ' : ' + val + '</br>');
        });
    }
};
```